# How to select values from JSON in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-5.7

can anyone tell me what is wrong with this query?

```
DECLARE @json LONGTEXT;

SET @json = '[ { "name":"John Smith",  "address":"780 Mission St, San Francisco, CA 94103"}, { "name":"Sally Brown",  "address":"75 37th Ave S, St Cloud, MN 94103"}, { "name":"John Johnson",  "address":"1262 Roosevelt Trail, Raymond, ME 04071"}     ]';

##SELECT @json;

SELECT * FROM JSON_TABLE (@json, '$[*]' COLUMNS (
                name VARCHAR(40)  PATH '$.name',
                address VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.address'));
```

The error that I get is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '(@json, '$[*]' COLUMNS (
> name VARCHAR(40)  PATH '$.name',
> ' at line 1

Just for Information I am using  TOAD as tool to connect to my cloud my sql instance.

Comment: No idea do you get a error or do you not get the expected results?

Comment: @RaymondNijland: Updated the question.

Comment: check mine answer i think it will help like i already said you need to write tricky MySQL code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, in mysql you don't need to declare a variable, in this case. Just use 'SET' keyword. And finaly, you need put an alias for your 'select' query. Like this:

```
SET @json = '[ { "name":"John Smith",  "address":"780 Mission St, San Francisco, CA 94103"}, { "name":"Sally Brown",  "address":"75 37th Ave S, St Cloud, MN 94103"}, { "name":"John Johnson",  "address":"1262 Roosevelt Trail, Raymond, ME 04071"}     ]';

##SELECT @json;

SELECT * FROM JSON_TABLE (@json, '$[*]' COLUMNS (
                `name` VARCHAR(40)  PATH '$.name',
                `address` VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.address')) AS T;
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(@json, '$[*]' COLUMNS (
                `name` VARCHAR(40)  PATH '$.name',
  ' at line 1

Comment: it does work @Sumit see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aTcuABmaw6AYXwADD19Ndi/0)..  If this errors. then you don't execute this on a MySQL 8 version and you will have to simulate/emulate the `JSON_TABLE()` function.

Comment: @RaymondNijland: yes the error is of Version. MySQL version that I am using is 5.7 and JSON_TABLE works in 8. Any suggestions how do i make it working in 5.7 ??

Comment: *"Any suggestions how do i make it working in 5.7"* Yes i might @Sumit but you are not going to like it, it involves writting tricky MySQL code.

Comment: @RaymondNijland: my main problem is that i want to bulk insert data in my sql using C#. Thats the problem i want to solve.

Comment: @RaymondNijland you can answer at my different question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55359772/how-to-bulk-insert-in-sql-using-dapper-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

> **Ideally you should be upgrading to MYSQL 8, this answer is more meant to have fun**

You need to write tricky SQL to simulate/emulate MySQL's 8.0 `JSON_TABLE()` in versions below MySQL 8

**Query**

```
SET @json = '[ { "name":"John Smith",  "address":"780 Mission St, San Francisco, CA 94103"}, { "name":"Sally Brown",  "address":"75 37th Ave S, St Cloud, MN 94103"}, { "name":"John Johnson",  "address":"1262 Roosevelt Trail, Raymond, ME 04071"}     ]';

##SELECT @json;

SELECT * FROM JSON_TABLE (@json, '$[*]' COLUMNS (
                `name` VARCHAR(40)  PATH '$.name',
                `address` VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.address')) AS T;
```

**Result**

```
| name         | address                                 |
| ------------ | --------------------------------------- |
| John Smith   | 780 Mission St, San Francisco, CA 94103 |
| Sally Brown  | 75 37th Ave S, St Cloud, MN 94103       |
| John Johnson | 1262 Roosevelt Trail, Raymond, ME 04071 |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aTcuABmaw6AYXwADD19Ndi/0)

MySQL's 5.7 simulate/emulate query involves using a number generator and multiple native MySQL's JSON functions.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(json_record.json, CONCAT('$[',number,'].name')), '"', '') AS name
 , REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(json_record.json, CONCAT('$[',number,'].address')), '"', '') AS address
FROM (
   SELECT 
     @row := @row + 1 AS number
   FROM (
      SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION   SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
      ) row1
      CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION  SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
    ) row2
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT @row := -1 
    ) init_user_params 
  ) AS number_generator
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT 
   JSON_LENGTH(json_information.json) - 1 AS json_length
 , json_information.json
FROM (
  SELECT 
    record.json
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      '
      [{
            "name": "John Smith",  
            "address": "780 Mission St, San Francisco, CA 94103"
      }, {
           "name": "Sally Brown",
           "address": "75 37th Ave S, St Cloud, MN 94103"
      }, {
           "name": "John Johnson",
           "address": "1262 Roosevelt Trail, Raymond, ME 04071"
      }]
     ' AS json
    FROM 
     DUAL   
  ) AS record  
) AS json_information

) AS json_record
WHERE 
 number BETWEEN 0 AND json_length
```

**Result**

```
| name         | address                                 |
| ------------ | --------------------------------------- |
| John Smith   | 780 Mission St, San Francisco, CA 94103 |
| Sally Brown  | 75 37th Ave S, St Cloud, MN 94103       |
| John Johnson | 1262 Roosevelt Trail, Raymond, ME 04071 |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8CbBfmnSxexnmFy6n1sRFM/1)

Comment: It's frankly easier to upgrade to MySQL 8.0.

Comment: I have to agree with Bill but this is a nice piece of coding.

Comment: *"I have to agree with Bill but this is a nice piece of coding"* @Nick thanks i also do upgrading to MySQL 8 is the most sensable did you notice -> *"Ideally you should be upgrading to MYSQL 8, this answer is more meant to have fun"*

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes, saw that comment. Sometimes you **need** to have fun.